# Set background color in Dash Plotly

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I'm working on a Dash App and I'm trying to set a background color for the entire page by creating a .css file in which I have:

```
body{
    background-color: darkcyan;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The problem is that the color is right but I still have white parts if there are graphs created with dcc.Graph

[image]

The color is darkcyan but it isn't working for graphs.
Here is my code for the plots creation:

```
dcc.Graph(figure=fig_length,
          style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'horizontal-align': 'right','vertical-align': 'up',"margin-top":"30px"}),
dcc.Graph(figure=fig_numbers,
          style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block',"margin-top":"30px"}),
dcc.Graph(figure=fig_clasification,
          style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block',"margin-top":"30px"}),

html.Div([
          dcc.Checklist(
          id="all-or-none",
          options=[{"label": "Select All", "value": "All"}],
          value=[],
          labelStyle={'margin-top': '10px'}
          )],style={"font-family": "Helvetica"}),
html.Div([
          dcc.Checklist(
          id='checklist_journals',
          options=[{'label': x, 'value': x, 'disabled': False}
                   for x in sorted(journals) #set in alphabetical order
                    ],
          value=sorted(journals)[0:15],
          labelStyle={'display': 'block','margin-left':'40px','margin-top':'10px'}
          )],style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block',"overflow-y":"scroll","height": "350px","font-family": "Helvetica"}), #'backgroundColor':'blue'
html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='journals_pie',figure=fig_pie_journals)],
          style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block',"font-family": "Helvetica"}),
html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='journals_graph', figure=fig1)],
         style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block',"font-family": "Helvetica"}),
```

I don't understand why the Checklist is coloured while the other graphs are white.

Comment: Have you tried adding ```'background-color': 'darkcyan'``` to your graphs' style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this for graph:

```
colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

 dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph-2',
        figure={
            'layout': {
                'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                'font': {
                    'color': colors['text']
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works